# Can't initialize Twitter Gem For Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've been trying to get the Twitter Gem running. I followed the documentation and placed

```
client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
config.consumer_key        = "YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY"
config.consumer_secret     = "YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET"
config.access_token        = "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN"
config.access_token_secret = "YOUR_ACCESS_SECRET"
end
```

I placed it in a custom initializer file called Twitter.rb

When I try to run rails console it gives me this error " uninitialized constant Twitter::REST (NameError)"

Answer (score 0):

This error was [reported here](https://github.com/sferik/twitter/issues/479)

The solution is to use `Twitter::Client.new` (no `::REST`)

Answer (score 0):

I faced with same issue. But I have installed two gems https://github.com/sferik/twitter and https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text-rb, they both have 'Twitter' as main module and when I call Twitter, I reached second instead first...

Twitter::Client.new - not working to.

Answer (score 0):

add require 'twitter' on the top of your file